# Bulk-allocating objects with calling new operator once?

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

I understand the basics about overloading the new operator for a particular class. However, one thing I do not understand if its possible. Say I have a class like this:

```
class X{
    int a;
    long b;
    float c;
}
```

and I wish to pre-create 100 X objects at the very beginning of my program. I would like to call the new operator just the once, to allocate (at least) (4 + 4 + 4?) x 100 = 1200 bytes. Then, whenever `X::new()` is called, instead of `new()` (`or malloc()`) being called, I will return the empty "shell" of an `X` object and then `a`, `b` and `c` are simply assigned to the data members.

How would I go about doing this? The emphasis on my question is that memory is only taken from the kernel once, when I reserve 1200 bytes for 100 X objects. After the beginning of my program I want the bare minimum to be executed when retrieving an X object "shell"?

Comment: Do you also want to be able to `delete` the objects, and if yes, in what order (arbitrary, opposite order of construction)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The emphasis on my question is that memory is only taken from the
>   kernel once, when I reserve 1200 bytes for 100 X objects. After the
>   beginning of my program I want the bare minimum to be executed when
>   retrieving an X object "shell"?

It sounds like what you're trying to do is akin to building a [memory pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool).

In a memory pool, you pre-allocate a large raw buffer where objects will eventually live.  Later you allocate individual objects within this buffer.  Doing this has the advantage of not having to allocate memory for each individual object -- all you have to do is construct the object within the pre-allocated space.  Since you don't have to go down to the kernel for each `Object` instantiated this way, there are potentially substantial time savings.  The drawback is you are taking responsibility for managing these objects in a more-direct way.  The code can be tricky, complex and bug-prone.

To allocate the raw buffer, we simply allocate a `char` array big enough to hold all the anticipated `Object`s:

```
char* buf = new char [1200];
```

In order to do the second part -- constructing an object within the memory pool -- you need to use [placement-new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).  Assuming `buf` is the location in the pre-allocated buffer where you want your new object `p` to be constructed:

```
Object* p = new (buf) Object();
```

When it comes time to destroy this object, do not use `delete`.  `delete` will attempt to deallocate the memory for the object, yielding undefined behavior and a likely crash since you didn't allocate the memory for the object<sup>1</sup>.  Instead, this is one case where you must call the destructor directly:

```
p->~Object();
```

Once all the objects have been destroyed, you can then release the buffer using `delete[]`:

```
delete [] buf;
```

---

Here is a complete example showing how to use placement-`new`, including construction of the buffer.  This uses the (implicitly defined) default constructor.  I'll show how to use another constructor later:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>  // required for placement-new
#include <iostream>


class X
{
public:
    int a;
    long b;
    float c;
};

int main()
{
    // construct the memory pool's buffer
    char* buf = new char [sizeof(X) * 1000];    // enough memory for 1000 instances of X

    // Instantiate 1000 instances of X using placement-new
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {   
        // Where in the memory pool shoudl we put this?
        char* buf_loc = buf + (sizeof(X) * i); 
        // Construct a new X at buf_loc
        X* new_x = new (buf_loc) X;
    }   


    // Do something with those instances
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {   
        // Where is the object?
        char* buf_loc = buf + (sizeof(X) * i); 
        X* my_x = reinterpret_cast <X*> (buf_loc);  // this cast is safe because I *know* that buf_loc points to an X

        // Let's assign some values and dump them to screen
        my_x->a = i;
        my_x->b = 420000 + i;
        my_x->c = static_cast <float> (i) + 0.42;

        std::cout << "[" << i << "]\t" << my_x->a << "\t" << my_x->b << "\t" << my_x->c << "\n";
    }   

    // Destroy the X's 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {   
        // Where is the object?
        char* buf_loc = buf + (sizeof(X) * i); 
        X* my_x = reinterpret_cast <X*> (buf_loc);  // this cast is safe because I *know* that buf_loc points to an X

        // Destroy it
        my_x->~X();
    }   

    // Delete the memory pool
    delete [] buf;
}
```

Now let's define a constructor for `X` which takes arguments:

```
class X
{
public:
    X (int aa, long bb, float cc)
    :
        a (aa),
        b (bb),
        c (cc)
    {
    }
    int a;
    long b;
    float c;
};
```

Since we've defined a constructor here, the compiler will no longer implicitly define a *default constructor* for `X`.

Let's use this new constructor.  The arguments to the constructor must now be passed:

```
   // Instantiate 1000 instances of X using placement-new
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        // Where in the memory pool shoudl we put this?
        char* buf_loc = buf + (sizeof(X) * i);
        // Construct a new X at buf_loc
        X* new_x = new (buf_loc) X(0,0,0.0f);
    }
```

---

**Do not use `delete`<sup>1</sup>**: Technically, the reason that using `delete` here yields *undefined behavior* is because `delete` can only be called with a pointer that was returned from a call to `new`.  Since you didn't `new` the object, but *placement*-`new`ed the object, you cannot call `delete`.

Comment: You can override operator new to use the memory pool and then not require placement new.  Would probably be much easier, assuming of course you never, ever use the class in any other way.  If you do, subclassing and overriding new for THAT class works.

Comment: @CrazyEddie:  Are you sure that's supported by the Standard?  I'm sure it works, at least where you've tried it, but since non-placement `new` is used to allocate memory, I wonder if not allocating memory in a `new` overload is legit according to the Standard.

Comment: Hi, thank for the detailed reply. Couple of questions- 1) why a char array? 2) Could you possibly show some basic code (relating to your example) for the new operator? I am unsure whether you actually create "shell" X objects using a default constructor and then the new operator assigns the data members?

Comment: @user997112:  A char array because a `char` is by definition exactly 1 byte in size (whatever a "byte" means to your platform), and you will avoid alignment problems by using it.  The code I posted was pretty much all there is to it.  I'm not creating any "shell" object here.  Calling placement-`new` will, of course, result in the constructor for your object being called.  In the above case, the default constructor is called since I didn't specify any parameters, but you can call whichever constructor you wish, just like with non-placement `new`.  Make sense?

Comment: @user997112:  I am constructing a complete example.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah.  Using your own allocation system is sortof the whole point of being able to override new.

Comment: @JohnDibling really appreciate the effort! One question- where/why have you not overloaded the new operator for the X class? I was expecting to see, in the X class, void* operator new(size_t size) etc?

Comment: @JohnDibling ah I think my last comment is basically what Eddie was referring to? How are these two approaches (what you have done and overloading new()) different?

Comment: @user997112:  I did not provide a new overload because it wasn't needed.  I suppose it could have been done, but in this program I saw no need.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost always a bad idea (see my paper, ["Reconsidering Custom Memory Allocation"](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/berger-oopsla2002.pdf), for a detailed discussion of why; in short, general-purpose allocators already optimize for the cases that custom allocators attempt to optimize).

Whenever you consider using a custom allocation scheme, you should ask yourself the following: have you actually measured the performance impact of using the default allocator (it is not always that much, and not clearly worth the risk of errors, etc.)? If it's actually the bottleneck, have you tried alternate allocators like [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org), [tcmalloc](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools), or [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is basically to implement your own memory manager.  You would probably find it easier to implement a factory class that you initialize to some large set of memory and just return the instances when they are requested.  To prevent these objects from being created by someone else, you can mark the constructors private (and make your factory class a friend).